# How set quantity to out of stock in Prestashop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

i'd like that when my product quantity is equal to 1, the product is out of stock ( and not when quantity is equal to 0 ).
Is it possible ?
How ?

Answer (score 0):

In PrestaShop 1.6 (tested and confirmed working in v1.6.0.14) you can accomplish this by the following method, where the website will always show an available stock quantity that is the real quantity minue one. If you have 6 in stock this modification will change your website to report the stock as 5 to your customers, when you have only 1 stock available, customers will see the product with 0 quantity and marked as out of stock.

1. *Copy* the file `/classes/stock/StockAvailable.php` to `/override/classes/stock/StockAvailable.php`.
2. *Edit* the file `/override/classes/stock/StockAvailable.php` as follows.

At lines 357-380 is the function `AvailableStock::getQuantityAvailableByProduct()` that will normally read like this (formatting may vary slightly):

```
public static function getQuantityAvailableByProduct( $id_product, 
                         $id_product_attribute = null, $id_shop = null ) {
  if( $id_product_attribute === null ) $id_product_attribute = 0;
  $skey = 'StockAvailable::getQuantityAvailableByProduct_' . (int)$id_product . '-' .
    (int)$id_product_attribute . '-' . (int)$id_shop;
  if( !Cache::isStored( $key )) {
    $query = new DbQuery();
    $query->select( 'SUM(quantity)' );
    $query->from( 'stock_available' );
    if( $id_product !== null ) $query->where( 'id_product = ' . (int)$id_product );
    $query->where( 'id_product_attribute = ' . (int)$id_product_attribute );
    $query = StockAvailable::addSqlShopRestriction( $query, $id_shop );
    Cache::store( $key, (int)Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->getValue( $query ));
  }
  return Cache::retrieve( $key );
}
```

Replace the last line of the function beginning with the keyword `return` to the following:

```
  $iStockQty = Cache::retrieve( $key );
  if( $iStockQty > 0 ) $iStockQty--;
  return $iStockQty;
```

3. *Delete* the file `/cache/class_index.php` so that Prestashop automatically re-creates this file taking into account the new override file.

Answer (score 0):

I also found the method `self::removeProductFromStockAvailable($id_product)` in StockAvailable.php to do some similar stuff.